# Prevent RNFirebase requesting notification permissions until button pressed

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase with FCM for React Native. I have a set of onboarding screens. Half way through it explains why we need to send notifications and *should* then show the alert that requests the permissions.

However, it seems that just including the line `[RNFirebaseNotifications configure];` in my AppDelegate.m makes it do it on installation of the app. I imagine though that removing this will just entirely stop Firebase Messaging from working!

How do I make it only request the permissions when I want it to, with `firebase.messaging().requestPermission();`?

Here is my AppDelegate.m

```c
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#if RCT_DEV
  #import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
#endif

#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"

#import <AppCenterReactNative.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNativeCrashes.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  #if RCT_DEV
    [bridge moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];
  #endif
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"foobar"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
  // Instantiate and configure Firebase.
  [FIRApp configure];
  // Configure the Firebase react-native notifications.
  [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];

  // Register Microsoft App Center.
  [AppCenterReactNative register];
  [AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics registerWithInitiallyEnabled:true];
  [AppCenterReactNativeCrashes registerWithAutomaticProcessing];

  if ([UNUserNotificationCenter class] != nil) {
    // iOS 10 or later
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
      UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
      requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
      completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          // ...
      }];
  }
  else {
    // iOS 10 notifications aren't available; fall back to iOS 8-9 notifications.
    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  }

  [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [RNSplashScreen show];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [CodePush bundleURL];
#endif
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}

-(void) userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:response.notification.request.content.userInfo];
  completionHandler();
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please only make edits if it actually helps people understand the question better. Changing half way to halfway is a complete unnecessary edit...